# Convering values stored within another language to case classes

Tags: scala, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap, circe

Rookie question here.

I have 2 apps that utilize Hazelcast, one is in Typescript and the other is in Scala. 
The Typescript app stores all the data and the Scala one interacts with it. 

I need an easy way to parse items inside of a map to a case class, this is easy if the HazelCast data is saved within Scala because it can be cast but when I attempt to do this with data stored from Typescript I get the following

```scala
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastJsonValue cannot be cast to TheCaseClass
```

I'm using circe and finch in the rest of the application, not sure if circe can be used here to parse it.

tl;dr Is there an easy way to convert HazelCast data stored in Typescript to a Scala case class.

Thanks

Comment: Might be good to show your code as well. The error message tells you that you're trying to cast the hazarlcast json into yuor case class, not parse it (so circe isn't used, likely)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just take one arbitrary class and cast it to another class. You have to parse them. If you use Hazelcast then probably [Hanzelcast Scala](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-scala) is what you should use.

[Wiki](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-scala/wiki/) suggest that you would have to do at least:

```
import com.hazelcast.Scala._

serialization.Defaults.register(conf.getSerializationConfig)
```

though it might require you to write your own [custom serialization](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-scala/wiki/Serialization#custom).

Comment: I'm using HazelCast Scala anyways, I'll look at custom serialization